# Import theme war file to eclipse - _diffs folder is empty

Tags: themes, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I'm working on Liferay themes and I'm trying to import the theme war file to my eclipse environment. I'm able to import the theme successfully by selecting the option Liferay --> Liferay Binary Plugin from import options. I'm able to deploy the new theme as well.
Problem is, I'm not seeing any folders inside the _diffs folder. Importing theme have folders inside the _diffs folder when creating. But not importing properly.
Any help is great helpful.

Comment: Try to import plugins copy of the same theme.

Comment: How do we get plugins for theme?